# How to use the privateIPAllocationMethod for vNet Gateway clients

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, openvpn, virtual-network

I have seen in my ARM template that this properties is available in the virtual network gateway.

However, the documentation does not seem to explain how to use it.

What I need is to create a virtual network gateway with OpenVPN point to site (up to this point, no problem, it is really easy) BUT I need to be able to configure static IPs for the clients.

The privateIPAllocationMethod look promising but I would expect to see further configuration to describe which client gets which IP.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, it does not support to configure static IPs for VPN clients. Every time a P2S connection goes live, the next available IP is allocated in the address range. Refer to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/3555907d-8c47-4d96-9bb4-cce8161b2e6b/azure-pointtosite-vpn-assign-static-ip?forum=WAVirtualMachinesVirtualNetwork).

In fact, the `privateIPAllocationMethod` is belonged to the `ipConfigurations` properties 
 in the `VirtualNetworkGatewayPropertiesFormat` object. What you need is to find the `VpnClientConfiguration` object, obviously, there is no such attribute to support the static IPs configuration for the clients. See `vpnclientconfiguration` in the [template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.network/2019-04-01/virtualnetworkgateways#vpnclientconfiguration-object) and the [Azure REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/network-gateway/virtualnetworkgateways/createorupdate#vpnclientconfiguration).

Comment: I'm accepting the answer as is for now but I hope to be able to come back soon when Microsoft has implemented that feature. I think my usecase is perfectly valid and I'm convinced that it should not be that hard to implement. Thanks for validating what I feared though!

Comment: You can upvote this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/33929980-static-ip-for-vpn-client-over-azure-p2s-solution) and wait for the response from the Azure product team.